# TortoiseGit fatal : can not hash , permission error

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit

Whenever I switch to a new branch some of my file permissions change like this

[image]

If I assign permissions here then once I switch again to a new branch, again the permissions change.

- I tried the revert option to get back without success.
- I tried using a new clone repository but experienced the same problem ...

Due to this problem I cannot switch to a new branch.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Are you certain that the branch(es) to which you are switching do not have permissions set this way?  I think the corrective action is to fix the permissions once and then branch from there.

Comment: I created new clone there if i switched new one some new files permissions are changed not a single file 5 to 6 file permission changed every  time

Comment: Maybe there is a settings problem with Windows?

Comment: Few hours back it works fine there is no issue... now i am getting this once again i will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your branch folder is present inside htdocs if it is there then..If that htdocs folder present inside C: drive will cause permission issue in some computer ...

Change your xampp installation in some other drive try.. Because in windows system UAC settings may cause this problem